# FB.getLoginStatus Javascript Not Working in IE11

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

using Facebook login javascript plugin to Facebook connect, version is 2.10. Most of the browsers are working (including Edge) except IE, anyone know why?

```
$('#Connect').click(function() {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function() {
    var response = FBProp.Res;
    console.log(response);
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
          handleConnections(response);
      } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {

          $("#fbconnect-btn").show();
          $("#btn-facebook-logout").hide();
          FB.login(function(response) {
              handleConnections(response);
          }, {
              scope: FBProp.Permissions.join(',')
          });
      } else {
          FB.login(function(response) {

              $("#fbconnect-btn").show();
              $("#btn-facebook-logout").hide();
              handleConnections(response);
          }, {
              scope: FBProp.Permissions.join(',')
          });
      }
  });

  })
```

The result of the console is "unknown" and it won't enter FB.login function in the else condition. Facebook is successfully connected but the pop up shows empty and will not close itself.

Comment: why "FBProp.Res"? why not FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {console.log(response);})?

Comment: ....and why use jQuery for the simple task of selecting by id (getElementById?) or adding a click listener? (addEventListener?) - just a side note...

Comment: @luschn response is "unknown" as well

Comment: ok, never had that problem. but something else is wrong with your code, you should not call FB.login in the asynchronous callback of FB.getLoginStatus, ONLY on user interaction. take a look at this article: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: @luschn tried to call "FB.login" function when onclick but it show the empty dialog box and doesn't close itself. only happened in IE11.

Comment: try with the exact code from my article and see if it still does not work. i never had any problems with IE11 with that code and it is still the same for the current api version.

Comment: @luschn it will show popup dialog but then doesnt close, and already connected to facebook.